# Jekyll: Display all posts in the same page

Tags: jekyll, blogs

I have been reading everything at [Jekyll Docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/), but I couldn't find a way to do this.

By default when generating a web, jekyll displays a list of the links of all your blog posts. Is there a way to display the content of all your blog posts in the same page? (alla blogspot/wordpress/traditional blog...)

Comment: "In the same page" would mean all the posts belonging to a specific category?

Comment: I meant in the home page of the blog

Answer (score 4):

Found my solution from: [This tutorial](https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/list-posts/), which consists of editing index.md and adding the following:

```
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  <article>
    <h2>
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        {{ post.title }}
      </a>
    </h2>
    <time datetime="{{ post.date | date: "%Y-%m-%d" }}">{{ post.date | date_to_long_string }}</time>
    {{ post.content }}
  </article>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That is also in Jekyll docs https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#displaying-an-index-of-posts